# How can Windows split its virtual memory space asymmetrically?

Tags: windows, kernel, x86-64, paging

According to the AMD64 Architecture Programmer's Manual Volume 2 (system programming), a logical address is valid only if the bits 48-63 are all the same as bit 47:

> 5.3.1 Canonical Address Form
>
> The AMD64 architecture requires implementations supporting fewer than the full 64-bit virtual address to ensure that those addresses are in canonical form. An address is in canonical form if the address bits from the most-significant implemented bit up to bit 63 are all ones or all zeros. If the addresses of all bytes in a virtual-memory reference are not in canonical form, the processor generates a general-protection exception (#GP) or a stack fault (#SS) as appropriate.

[image]

So it seems the only valid address ranges are 0x0000_0000_0000_0000 ~ 0x0000_7FFF_FFFF_FFFF and 0xFFFF_8000_0000_0000 ~ 0xFFFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF, that is, the lower 128 TiB and higher 128 TiB. However, according to MSDN, the addresses used by Windows x64 kernel don't seem to be the case.

> In 64-bit Windows, the theoretical amount of virtual address space is 2^64 bytes (16 exabytes), but only a small portion of the 16-exabyte range is actually used. The 8-terabyte range from 0x000'00000000 through 0x7FF'FFFFFFFF is used for user space, and portions of the 248-terabyte range from 0xFFFF0800'00000000 through 0xFFFFFFFF'FFFFFFFF are used for system space.

So, how can Windows split the virtual address space into lower 8 TiB and higher 248 TiB, despite the hardware specification? I'd like to know why it doesn't cause any problems with the hardware that checks whether the addresses are canonical.

**UPDATE: ** Seems like Microsoft fixed this discrepancy in Windows 8.1. See https://www.facebook.com/codemachineinc/posts/567137303353192 for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right; current x86-64 hardware with 48-bit virtual address support requires that the high 16 bits be the sign-extension of the low 48 (i.e. bit 47 matches bits `[63:48]`).  That means about half of the `0xFFFF0800'00000000` to `0xFFFFFFFF'FFFFFFFF` range is non-canonical on current x86-64 hardware.

Windows is just describing how it carves up the full 64-bit virtual address space, *not* which parts of that are actually in use on current x86-64 hardware.  It can of course only use the 128 TiB that is canonical, from `0xFFFF8000'00000000` to `-1`.  (Note the position of the `8`; there's no gap between it and the high 16 bytes that are all-ones, unlike in the theoretical Windows range.)

Top-end servers can be built with 6TiB of RAM or maybe even more.  ([Xeon  Platinum Scalable Processors](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/skylake_(server)#All_Skylake_Chips) are apparently available with up to 1.5TiB per socket, and up to 8-way, e.g. the 8180M).

Intel has proposed an extension for larger physical and virtual addressing that adds another level of page tables,   https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/2b/80/5-level_paging_white_paper.pdf, so OSes will hopefully not be stuck without enough virtual address space to map all the RAM (like in the bad old days of PAE on 32-bit-only systems) before we have systems that have more than 128TiB of physical RAM.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on this. I've looked up Windows Internals and it seems like the address space is indeed used in a top-down fashion, not reaching the lower threshold of 0xFFFF8000_00000000 when there is only a small amount of RAM.